# sqlite: not returning email address (org.sqlite.RS)

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a email column in my database which contains the users email address, i can use the following statement

```
select email from student where fname = 'john' and lname = 'daly'
```

when i call this using the following code

```
 String result = null;
        connection = ConnectDb();
        stat = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next())
   {
    result =rs.getString(0);
    }

        closeAll();            
        return result;
```

i get the following result `org.sqlite.RS@546984`, im guessing this is because i need to return the result as a `resultSet`, i can do this for multiple values but i cannot figure it out for just a single value

Any know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like thi:

//Any way you know only one will be returned, so while excute only once.

```
   ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.hasNext())
   {
    result =rs.getString("email");
    }
```

Comment: i have tried this already but all seems to return is the heading of the column `email` and not the email address itself

Comment: the code i have above is the latest code, i have tried to use resultSet (and your above code) but doesnt work

Comment: your code above gave the following error `java.sql.SQLException: column 0 out of bounds [1,1]` and when i debugged it, it still returned `email` and not the email address. which is weird because when i run the statement using sqlite it returns the correct values

Comment: well there is the code i am using at the moment but it is still giving the errors i mentioned above

Comment: just tried it there and it work :) why did 'email' work do any not re.getString(0)?

Comment: Sqllite result set expects column name while doing getString() instead of index.